# Schwarzschild and Einstein Field Equation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

In his paper [Über das Gravitationsfeld eines Massenpunktes nach der Einsteinsche Theorie](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1916SPAW.......189S) Schwarzschild used this equation (Paper eq. (4)):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\alpha}\Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu\nu}+\Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu\beta}\,\Gamma^\beta{}_{\nu\alpha}=0$$
for Einstein Field Equation $G_{\mu\nu}=0$ where $\Gamma$ is the Christoffel symbol. How is this form of the equation obtained?

Comment: The vacuum equations can be shown to be just $R_{\mu\nu}=0$. I believe he is also demanding the metrict to have determinant equal to $-1$. In that case using the formula for the Ricci tensor you may find here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry the equation follows. I believe it is this.

Comment: I may be wrong on my history, but I think your question may amount to "Why didn't Schwarzschild use notation that hadn't been standardized at the time that he wrote his paper?"

Comment: In this paper Schwarzschild develop his famous metric that solve the Einstein Field equation , so I don’t think there is any simplifications

Comment: @Brick I think that the Schwarzschild Field equations are equivalent to Einstein field equations ? this is my question .

Comment: I didn't work it out by hand, but I believe that is the Einstein field equation in the case relevant to the paper. But close enough to the development of the Einstein equations that people may not have settled on notation that we use today.

Comment: @Eli Did you understand the first comment? It is the explanation.

Comment: No perhaps you can write the equations as a answer?, in this paper I don’t see the Schwarzschild  equation

Comment: I don’t understand your last comment. Did you mean to say that you don’t see the *Einstein* field equation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @user1620696 in the first comment to your question pointed out,
the Einstein field equations in vacuum can be shown to be just
$$ R_{\mu\nu} = 0, \tag{a}$$

and in the [List of formulas of Riemannian geometry - Ricci and scalar curvatures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Ricci_and_scalar_curvatures)
you find (among others) this formula for the Ricci curvature tensor:
$$ R_{ik} = \frac{\partial \Gamma^l{}_{ik}}{\partial x^l} - \Gamma^m{}_{il} \Gamma^l{}_{km}
 - \nabla_k \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\left(\log\sqrt{|g|}\right)\right). \tag{b}$$

Because Schwarzschild also demands the "determinant equation" (equation (5) in [his paper](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber_das_Gravitationsfeld_eines_Massenpunktes_nach_der_Einsteinschen_Theorie))
$$ |g| = -1, $$
the last summand in equation (b) vanishes, and you are left with

$$ R_{ik} = \frac{\partial \Gamma^l{}_{ik}}{\partial x^l} - \Gamma^m{}_{il} \Gamma^l{}_{km} . \tag{c}$$

Putting equations (a) and (c) together, you get
$$ \frac{\partial \Gamma^l{}_{ik}}{\partial x^l} - \Gamma^m{}_{il} \Gamma^l{}_{km} = 0 $$

This is apart from naming of the indexes the same as Schwarzschild's equation (4).

Comment: Thank you for your answer